# Using Powershell to create custom install strings from CSV input

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I'm mostly just looking to be pointed in the right direction so I can piece it together myself. I have a decent amount of batch file scripting experience. I'm a PS noob but I think PS would be better for the project below.

We have software which requires the client ID to be part of the install string (along with switches, usr/pass, other switches, logging paths, etc).

I've created a batch file (hundreds actually) which I execute with `PSEXEC` on remote machines which does work but it's burly to maintain. The only change in each is the client ID.

What I'm attempting to do is have a CSV with 2 columns as input (so I just have to maintain the CSV): machine name (as presented by `%hostname%`) & client ID. I want to create a script which matches `%hostname%` to a corresponding row in column 1, read the data in column 2 of the same row, and then be able to call that as a variable in the install string.

E.G.
If my CSV has `bobs-pc` in column 1, row 6, then insert the data from column 2, row 6 (let's call it 0006) in the following install string:

```
install.exe /client_ID=0006
```

*no looping* 
I don't want it to install on all machines simultaneously due to the multiple time zones we operate in.

Something like this would be really useful for many projects I have so I'm more interested in learning than having anyone write it for me.

I understand I should be using `Import-Csv`. I've created a sample csv and can get certain fields to print out in PS. What I need is for a script to be able to insert those fields as variables in the install string.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want something along the lines of this, (assumes your CSV has a header row of col1 and col2):

```
$hostname = 'server1'
$value = Import-CSV myfile.csv | where { $_.col1 -eq $hostname } | select -expandproperty col2

Install.exe /client_id=$value
```